# Вертикальное выравнивание ссылок меню на css

Tags: html, css, flexbox, выравнивание

Пытаюсь разобраться с созданием меню на css. Имеется вроде как стандартное горизонтальное меню, с выпадающим из второго пункта подменю. Вот как оно должно выглядеть:
1. Ссылка должна срабатывать при нажатии на свободную область блока вокруг неё, а не только на саму ссылку.
2. Текст ссылок должен быть выровнен вертикально по центру пункта меню (в том числе двухстрочный текст).

Проблема которая у меня возникают при попытке это реализовать:
Задаю ссылке блочный тип и высоту, чтобы ссылка срабатывала при нажатии на свободное место вокруг - текст ссылки смещается и отказывается центрироваться по вертикали. Соответственно в итоге получаю либо п.1, либо п.2, одновременно оба пункта не получается реализовать.

Изначально пытался использовать flexbox при создании меню, и все вроде бы шло легко, но выпадающее подменю в таком случае выпадало почему-то по центру пункта меню, а не под ним (выравнивалось вместе со всеми пунктами меню).

В итоге вообще запутался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На.

```css
.nav-bar {
  background: #99f;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.menu li {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.menu>li {
  flex: 1;
}

.menu a {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu li a div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #D2908B;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu .sub-menu a {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding:3px 5px;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: salmon;
}

.menu>li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 17px;
  width: 300px;
}

.search-form .search-text {
  background-image: url(images/glass.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 13px 5px;
  text-indent: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.0625rem;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">
        <div>Главная</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="organizations.html">
        <div>Учреждения и организации</div>
      </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#1">Учреждение 1 длиииииииииинный текст</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Учреждение 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">Учреждение 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="shedule.html">
        <div>Расписание</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="about.html">
        <div>Объявления</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="feedback.html">
        <div>О сайте</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```